Set theory: how do I "distribute" overlapping sets?
Let me preface by saying that I'm a software engineer; I'm neither a mathematician nor a logician in the academic sense. So I apologize if terms / symbols are not accurate for representing sets.
EDIT: I agree with commenters that the original text I had was worded way too confusingly.
I've boiled it down to what I think is the simplest example I can think of.

Say I have this sequence/set: abcd, with each letter representing a distinct item.
In the domain language I'm using, any item or groups of items can be extended. So, say I extend b with e. That means that we need to represent 2 new sequences: abcd and aecd, but a proper way to structure this would be a(b|e)cd with the group of items that will be distributed across sequences. If I were to extend cd with f, then the list would be a(b|e)(cd|f) as the smallest possible representation of this list, which represents all list combinations.
So, let's start again with abcd.

Given abcd, here is a list of extensions to be made, with the bracketed search (the "find") and => listing what it is extended with:

[abc]d => h
abc[d] => e
ab[c]d => g
ab[cd] => f

Meaning:

[abc] will be [abc] OR [h] -- represented as (abc|h)d
[d] will be [d] OR [e] -- taking prev. as input, represented as (abc|h)(d|e)
[c] will be [c] OR [g] -- (ab(c|g)|h)(d|e)
[cd] will be [cd] OR [f] -- ???

I'm stumped as to how to determine the simplest representation of combinations of items for the last one. If I were to substitute the last item first, it would be ab(cd|f), but once lists are overlapping, I'm unsure how to mathematically / algorithmically determine the smallest possible set representation.
ORIGINAL QUESTION:
To try to boil this problem down, I'm working on a stylesheet language. Let's say I have this set:
{ .one, .two, .three.four } (For the purpose of simplification, consider these strings, or arrays of strings i.e. it's represented more like: { '.one', '.two', ['.three', '.four'] }
I can "extend" this set and represent it as nested sets. So, for example:

Given the above, I can extend .four with .five, this creates the nested set:
{ .one, .two, .three{ .four, .five } } (with the actual data structure in memory being like { '.one', '.two', ['.three', { '.four', '.five' }] }
Continuing on, given the result of the #1, I extend .three.four with .six. This creates the set { .one, .two, { .three{ .four, .five }, .six } }
Continuing, I extend .three with .seven, and I the resulting set should be: { .one, .two, { { .three, .seven }{ .four, .five }, .six } }
Now, the following is where my brain breaks. I want to extend {.one, .two, .three} with .eight. In other words, had I started with { .one, .two, .three } and I extended with .eight, the end result would be: { { .one, .two, .three }, .eight }. With the result from #2, however, I need to redistribute such that I end up with a set like: { .one, .two, { { .three, .seven }{ .four, .five }, .six}, { .eight{ { .four, .five } } } or  { { .one, .two, .three }, .eight }{ { .three, .four }, { .one, .two, { { .six{ .four, .five }, .six } }

So, I know what the possible results should be for the smallest grouping of distributed sets.
Another way to phrase the problem (maybe this is simpler to demonstrate):

Say I have a set  { abxy }.
I want to extend { ab } with { c }, which would result in { abxy, cxy }. However, I want to represent this as the simplest set: { (ab|c)xy }
Now, I want to extend { bx } with { d }. Again, if this were distributed, it would be { abxy, cxy, dy }. However, how do I algorithmically calculate the simplest set, and duplicate items that need to be distributed? I can represent this as { ((ab|c)x|d)y } as the simplest possible form, but then how do I extend { cx } with { e } or { xy } with { f } from that simple form?

I hope one or both of those explanations make sense. Any help figuring this out algorithmically would be appreciated!

Why would you ask you question in this forum with strings ".one", ".two", etc. You should try to simplify your notation, trying to read "{ { .one, .two, .three }, .eight }{ { .three, .four }, { .one, .two, { { .six{ .four, .five }, .six } }" is way more difficult than reading something like "{ {1,2,3}, 8}{ { 3, 4 }, { 1, 2, { { 6 { 4, 5 }, 6 } }"

I think the concepts that you manipulate here have very little to do with sets in the mathematical sense. It looks like you are considering languages in the sense of computer science, for example the language that contains the words 'abxy', 'cxy' and 'dy' and you try to build a short regular expression that accepts this language. You may be looking for Kleene's algorithm that transforms finite automatons into regular expressions for example. Also many things are unclear in the question, especially the word 'extend'  eg How does extending {b x } with {d } lead to { abxy, cxy, dy } ?

Mathematically you could also consider certain types of graphs (here, rooted trees perhaps) with the nodes labeled by the strings. That's probably how a computer language would implement this kind of structure anyway.

Why "nested sets" whereas it looks to me that trees with nodes holding information would make the job ? Trees belong to mathematics as parts of graph theory.

Does "extend" have anything to do with the extends keyword in Java or JavaScript?

I think you can just represent the expressions as finite automatons, for example with the expression (ab(c|g)|h)(d|e), if you allow replacing cd by f it gives the following DFA

Algebraically, I see two short ways of factoring the graph using the notations of Kleene algebras
\begin{equation}
(ab(c+g)+h)(d+e)+abf = ab((c+g)(d+e)+f)+h(d+e)
\end{equation}
Kleene's algorithm could probably transform the graph into an algebraic expression but the result depends on the ordering of the vertices of the graph. With only 5 nodes, you could take the best of the 120 possible orders.
Also you would probably get more powerful answers on cs.stackexchange.com

This is a great answer in creating a linked node representation, but how would you do this: "With only 5 nodes, you could take the best of the 120 possible orders." How do you mathematically determine the best?

@MatthewDean You have to define the meaning of the "best" algebraic expression. In your post, you speak about the smallest possible algebraic expression. The length of the expression or the number of operators could be the criterion.

[+1] May I ask you which software you use for generating such graphs (Tikz ?)

@JeanMarie For this one I used the Python module pythomata. Several modules exist in Python for finite state automata. They usually convert the automaton to Graphviz's Dot language to draw it. Just search the Python Package Index https://pypi.org/

@Gribouillis Thanks !
